# Cargar datos en TextBox usando ComboBox conectado con SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estoy tratando de llenar un textbox de productos a partir de un combobox que muestra su abreviación, el problema es que no importa cual de todos los items del combo seleccione, en el textbox solo aparece el primer producto que tengo en mi tabla. 
Agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

```
//Esto lo uso para cargar la información en el combobox 
        SqlCommand comando_Clave = new SqlCommand("SELECT Mostrar_Como FROM Productos", conexion);
        conexion.Open();
        SqlDataReader registro_Clave = comando_Clave.ExecuteReader();
        while (registro_Clave.Read())
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(registro_Clave["Mostrar_Como"]).ToString();

        }
        conexion.Close();
//Y esto lo uso para cargar la informacion en el textbox
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Productos", conexion);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("Nombre_Productos", comboBox1.SelectedItem);
        conexion.Open();
        SqlDataReader registro = comando.ExecuteReader();
        if (registro.Read())
        {
            textBoxConcepto.Text = registro["Nombre_Productos"].ToString();
        }
        conexion.Close();
```

[image]

Comment: Asumo que estás usando WinForms... ¿En qué evento tienes ese código? Revisa que no lo hayas puesto en el _ValueChanged() y esté en el método que carga tu forma.

Comment: La carga de datos del combo lo tengo en Load() y para mostrar los datos en el textbox lo entengo en SelectedIndexChanged() del combo.

Comment: Creo que estas haciendo mal lo siguiente: Primero si tienes la informacion ya descargada en el combobox, para que haces una consulta a la base de datos de nuevo?. Deberias usar selectedItem o SelectedIndex de tu combo box para pasar ese valor al textbox. Segundo: en tu consulta le pasas un parametro pero la consulta no tiene ningun where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cargar los items del combo asigna el `DataSource`

```
public void Form1_Load(...)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id, Mostrar_Como FROM Productos", conexion);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Mostrar_Como";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
    comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Tienes que identificar cual es el id o key de la tabla que permita identificar el producto.

Entonces en el evento `SelectionChangeCommitted` ya que se ejecuta cuando el usuario cambia la seleccion

[ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted Evento](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted?view=netframework-4.8)

Entonces quedaria

```
public void combobox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(...)
{
    conexion.Open();

    string query = "SELECT Nombre_Productos FROM Productos WHERE Id = @id";
    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query, conexion);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", comboBox1.SelectedValue);

    SqlDataReader registro = comando.ExecuteReader();
    if (registro.Read())
    {
        textBoxConcepto.Text = registro["Nombre_Productos"].ToString();
    }

    conexion.Close();
}
```

Usa el `SelectedValue` para tomar el valor del Id o key asignado al item del combo, este lo aplicas el `WHERE` del `SELECT`